# Comparing two column names in PowerShell Datatables

Tags: .net, datatable, powershell-4.0

I need to compare two text files with these columns in two datatables, dt1 and dt2:

File1: A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7,A8,A9,10

File2: A1,A2,A4,A6,A8,A9,A10,A11,A12,A13,A14

I need the row values for the columns in File1 to be copied to File2 and if the column doesn't exist in File1, then insert a pipe

I tried this:

```
foreach($col in $dt2.Columns)
        {                          
            if($dt1.Columns.Contains($col.ColumnName))
            {
            [void]$line.Append($dt1.Rows[$i][$col1.ColumnName]) 
            [void]$line.Append("|")                                  
            }
            else 
            {[void]$line.Append("|")}       
        }
```

$line is the StringBuilder object.

I also tried comparing each column in File 1 with each in File2 with nested foreach loops but that didn't help either. I took and enumerator for the datatable columns and used a while loop to move next and then take the current pointer but that too to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

the Columns property ($dt2.Columns) does not return an array of column name strings, but an array of DataColumns.
therefore, your Contains() method should be run on
$dt1.Columns.ColumnName
and not on
$dt1.Columns